Android Studio System UI is not visible
System UI
I enabled the System UI from the settings, but it is still not visible. How can I fix this?
I have already reinstalled the application and tried to remove and reupload the SKT tools, but it's still not working. I also tried restarting my device multiple times to see if that would resolve the issue, but unfortunately, it did not. I checked online for any potential solutions or similar issues experienced by others, but I couldn’t find anything that worked.
